# DataGridView with Groupheaders spanning the entire row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, grouping

I was wondering if there was any way of getting the Datagridview to group it's line by a Property in it's datasource (Not used in the columns) and add the grouping header as well. I've added a picture for reference.

[image]

I did override the Defaultcell style to have alternatives (like "No Nuts") available, and I know i can "just group the datasource" to have it sorted/grouped. however I would like to have these groupheaders as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you look into ListView? Out of the box DGV is not really helpful for this. Or use one of the custom made subclasses from out there.

Comment: Thanks  @TaW, I did try making it work with ListView as well. However the solution is more of a Inherit BindingList<T> approach giving me the option of adding in new lines for each grouping and overriding the CellPaint event to make sure the value, FormattedValue and alignment corresponds. I don't have the finished product yet (spaghetti code), but I'll post a result when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made another layer on top of the BindingList from the datasource and put this as the Datasource.

```
    public class GroupedBindingList : BindingList<OrderlineModel>
{
   

     public BindingList<OrderlineModel> OriginalList { get; set; }
        public SortedDictionary<int, BindingList<OrderlineModel>> GroupedOrderlineDict;
        public GroupedBindingList(BindingList<OrderlineModel> list)
        {
            OriginalList = list;
            GroupedOrderlineDict = new();
            GroupBy();
            OriginalList.ListChanged += OriginalList_ListChanged;
        }
        protected GroupedBindingList() { }
    }
```

I could then add the grouby function and use a extension of the lines in the datasource object to determen if the line I was dealing with a header or a normal line.
I also hooked onto the original list changed event to refresh and regroup the grid given an item was added or reset.
Made this the center piece of a user control and it works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone else!